# How do I call a function only once during a specific scroll height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map on the bottom of my webpage and when a user scrolls down to the map, I want the google marker to drop and that specific time. I have this working already. The problem is that it keeps calling the function, how do I call it only once?

This is my JS code right now and I have tried to figure the bug out:

```
      $(window).scroll(function () {

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300 && 
        $(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
        ) {

        var dropOnlyOnce = (function(){  

            dropped = false;
            if (dropped == false) {
                dropMarker(); // this is the function I'm calling
            }
            dropped = true;

        })();

     } 

  });
```

How can I get this to work or how can I just call the dropMarker function once?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the listener once the function has been called:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
  if( ...window at scrollTop ) {

    $(window).off('scroll')
    .... Drop your pin
  }
})
```

Esteban Felix's Comment brings up a good point. This will remove all scroll handlers. If that's not something that works for you, you can move the function outside the handler, and only remove that:

```
var dropPinOnce = function() {
  if( ... window at correct scrollTop ) {
    ... Drop pin here ...
    $(window).off('scroll', dropPinOnce)
}

$(window).on('scroll', dropPinOnce)
```

Comment: This would turn off all of the scroll events which may or may not matter in the questioner's case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once")
, dropMarker = function() {
    // do stuff
}; 
callbacks.add(dropMarker);

$(window).scroll(function () {

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300 && 
        $(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
        ) {    
        var dropOnlyOnce = (function(){      
            dropped = false;
            if (dropped == false) {
                callbacks.fire() // call `dropMarker` "once"
            }
            dropped = true;   
        })();   
     }    
  });
```

See [jQuery.Callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) at "Possible Flags" -> "once"

```js
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once")
, dropMarker = function() {
    console.log(123)
}; 

callbacks.add(dropMarker);

$(window).scroll(function () {

     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 300 && 
        $(window).scrollTop() <= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200
        ) {

        var dropOnlyOnce = (function(){  

            dropped = false;
            if (dropped == false) {
               // dropMarker(); // this is the function I'm calling
                callbacks.fire()
            }
            dropped = true;

        })();

     } 

  });
```

```css
div {
  height : 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: That's pretty clever! Only drawback is the scroll handler is still being called several times a second when it's it not needed.

Comment: @jhummel Not certain from Question whether scroll event still utilized for other tasks ? Could add `$(window).on("scroll.namespace")` to piece , `$(window).off("scroll.namespace")` to closing line of `dropMarker` ; if scroll event only to call `dropMarker` once . If other scroll events attached to window , still called on scroll; see http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you just unbind after your condition is met then your function will effectively only be called once.

```
$(window).scroll(function callOnceOnScroll() {
    var $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document);
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= $document.height() - $window.height() - 300 &&
        $window.scrollTop() <= $document.height() - $window.height() - 200) {

        $window.off('scroll', callOnceOnScroll);
        dropMarker(); // this is the function I'm calling
    }

});
```